# Como modificar el valor de un servicio y mostrarlo en pantalla?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo un app con MEAN, es para visualizar el status online de la lista de amigos de un usuario, ahora, primero cargo la lista de amigos de ese id , a esa consulta debo agregar el status, que se encuentra en otra colección

Así lo estoy haciendo:

```
 getFriends(){
this.userService.getFriends().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.friends = result;

    this.friends.forEach(friend => {
      friend.status = this.cargarStatus(friend.id);
      console.log(friend.status)
    })

    console.log(this.friends)
  }, (error)=> {
    console.log(error)
  }
)
```

}

Ahora, como pueden notar this.friends, es un modelo que contiene id, name, status, pero el servicio que da consulta a esa lista de amigos no tiene el apartado de status, ese viene en otra, por lo que intento modificar this.friend.status de cada elemento mandando a llamar un método que es este:

```
cargarStatus(idUser:string):string{
let stat:string;
const json = {
  id:idUser
}
this.userService.getStatus(json).subscribe(
  result => {
    stat = result.status
    console.log(stat)
  },(error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }
)

return stat
```

}

Ahora, si imprimo `this.friends` o como se ve en el primer bloque de código `friend.status` este sale como `undefined`, sin embargo, si imprimo la consulta en la función de `cargarStatus` la variable `stat` antes del return si regresa lo que deseo, pero jamás llega a cambiar `this.friends`, lo que me causa una mala sensación es que si lo modifico manualmente es decir si en vez de usar un servicio para cargar stat se lo pongo directamente, si funciona,tanto por consola como en la vista, a que se deberá?, ¿qué estaré haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Estás mezclando ejecución síncrona y asíncrona. el método `cargarStatus` nunca te va a devolver el valor obtenido porque no espera a que se obtenga para completar su ejecución. Podrías hacer algo así:

```js
cargarStatus(user:User) {
  this.userService.getStatus({id: user.id}).subscribe(
    result => {
      user.status= result.status
      console.log(user.status)
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  )
}
```

Pasas todo el `user` a la función y que ésta actualice el valor cuando lo obtenga.